# Simulating bivariate Pareto distribution

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, correlation, pareto-chart

I am looking for a package/ code that would generate bivariate Pareto distribution, when two random variables are correlated (and the correlation can be specified by the user). I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any existing R packages, but found your question interesting; so I would like to show you a way how to sample from the [bivariate type I Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_Pareto_distribution#Bivariate_Pareto_distribution_of_the_first_kind) using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

---

## Theory

The joint pdf of the bivariate Pareto distribution of type I is given by

[image]

The goal here is to

1. draw samples for *x2* from the marginal distribution *f(x2)*, and then
2. draw samples for *x1* given *x2* from the conditional distribution *f(x1|x2)*.

The marginal and conditional distributions are given by (see e.g. [[Mardia, Annals of Mathematical Statistics 33, 1008 (1962)]](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704468))

[image]

We can draw samples using inverse transform sampling, which requires the cumulative distribution functions for both the marginal and conditional distributions. That's easy to calculate, and we get

[image]

Then samples for *x1* and *x2* are given by

[image]

where *u* is a random number from the standard uniform distribution in the interval [0,1].

---

## R implementation

1. We define two functions to sample values for *x1* and *x2* from the marginal and conditional distributions using inverse transform sampling as detailed above.

   ```
   rpareto_inv <- function(n, theta, a) {
       u <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1);
       return(theta / (u ^ (1 / a)));
   }


   rpareto_cond_inv <- function(x2, theta1, theta2, a) {
     u <- runif(length(x2), min = 0, max = 1);
     return(theta1 + theta1 / theta2 * x2 * (1 / (u ^ (1 / (a + 1))) - 1));
   }
   ```
2. We chose some values for the sampling and distribution parameters:

   ```
   n <- 10^5;     # Number of samples
   theta1 <- 5;   # Location parameter 1
   theta2 <- 2;   # Location parameter 2
   a <- 3;        # Shape parameter
   ```
3. Now we can draw samples

   ```
   set.seed(2017);
   x2 <- rpareto_inv(n, theta = theta2, a = a);
   x1 <- rpareto_cond_inv(x2, theta1, theta2, a);
   ```
4. We can show a 2d density plot and compare some sample summary statistics with their theoretical (population) values.

   ```
   require(ggplot2);
   df <- cbind.data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2);
   ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2)) +
       geom_density_2d() +
       xlim(theta1, 1.5 * theta1) +
       ylim(theta2, 1.5 * theta2);
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   metrics <- cbind.data.frame(
       obsrv = c(mean(df$x1), mean(df$x2), cor(df$x1, df$x2), cov(df$x1, df$x2)),
       theor = c(a * theta1 / (a - 1), a * theta2 / (a - 1), 1/a, theta1 * theta2 / ((a - 1)^2 * (a - 2))));
   rownames(metrics) <- c("Mean(x1)", "Mean(x2)", "Correlation", "Covariance")
   #                obsrv     theor
   #Mean(x1)    7.4947124 7.5000000
   #Mean(x2)    3.0029318 3.0000000
   #Correlation 0.3429634 0.3333333
   #Covariance  2.3376545 2.5000000
   ```

   You can see that the agreement is good. Also note that the correlation between *x1* and *x2* is characterised by the scale parameter *a*. Consequently, if you wanted to simulate data for a bivariate Pareto distribution with a specific correlation *r*, you'd just need to set the shape parameter to *1/r*. More details on the distribution and additional summary statistics can be found in [[Mardia, Annals of Mathematical Statistics 33, 1008 (1962)]](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704468).

Lastly, you could also use a simple accept-reject sampling method, but I imagine that being a lot slower than the inverse transform sampling approach I'm showing here.

Comment: Dear Maurits, thank you for such a clear and detailed response. It is mostly appreciated and answers all my question.

Comment: No problem @Arbiturka, glad I could help. This was a fun problem.